# Prism register and unregister Singleton

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, singleton, prism

In my App.xaml.cs file I register singleton for my class like below

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<MyPageViewModel>();
}
```

The problem comes when I first log in for example with English selected, go to MyPage, then log out and switch to Ukrainian. I created a MyPage instance with an English title and that's what the singleton contains for me.

This is how I set page Title in ViewModel:

```
public MyPageViewModel()
{
   Title = AppResources.MyPage_Caption;
}
```

The logout function is simply calling the navigation service back to the login page from the home page like this:

```
private async Task LogoutAsync()
{
   await navigationService.NavigateAsync("/LoginPage/");
}
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to unregister or terminate this singleton when I log out of my application

Comment: A singleton view model is not a good idea. Also, there's no unregistering with the container.

Comment: I use it to store my inputs when I navigate between multiple pages

Answer (score 1):

While there is most certainly a better way to handle the way you're storing data, here is the answer to the question you asked.

The easiest way to solve this is to add a `Reset` method to your VM. Inside the method, cleanup whatever variables you need to. You can then call the reset method as needed.

Comment: The problem is that I set the page titles in their viewmodel constructors, so it's hard for me to change the title when a specific page is opened

Could you also refer to a better way to handle my data storage?